# Adding sub panel in my basement

Tags: wiring, subpanel

I want to install a sub panel in my basement directly below my kitchen.  44 foot run to the main panel. Can I use 6/4 SOOW wire instead of AWG?  This panel will eventually have a transfer switch on it to work with a generator.  It will carry all of my kitchen, ( two freezers, microwave, coffee maker, toaster ) the basement sump pump and my propane furnace.  I intend to use a 60 amp sub panel with 8-10 available circuit breakers.  Also - this feed will be mounted on the face of a support beam that traverses the length of my basement.  What is the code-appropriate way to mount this cable on the face of that beam?  I intend to run this wire myself, then hire an electrician to do the actual connections on both ends.

Comment: Are you planning to use a generic portable generator, or did you have a specific generator in mind?

Comment: No.  I have a 6500 watt gasoline generator outside in a shed butted up against the back of my house.

Comment: What make and model is said generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWG is the name of the wire size, e.g. you want to use 6 AWG wire.

SOOW is a cable type, however it is *cordage* and not allowed for building wiring.

You want NM-B or possibly UF-B.

---

It needs to be protected from physical damage, i.e. getting beaned by people moving furniture or carrying in a ladder or whatever.  If you must mount it on the face of the beam,  your best bet is to install it in EMT conduit, which provides physical protection.  However, at that point, you are better off running the EMT all the way from panel to panel, and then, using THHN individual wires in the pipe.  A neat side effect of this is you can run an extra 10 amps, so 70A.

---

If you lived in Wyoming and drove 85 mph every day, would you want 85 mph rated tires on your car?  Of course not, you don't want to be at safety redline all the time.   So do not get a "60A" panel.  Get more like a 125-200A panel that has **plenty of spaces**. Like huge numbers of spaces.  Like 30 spaces.

Get a Siemens main-lug panel. This will allow you to use [this here transfer switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-Standby-Power-Interlock-Kit-ECSBPK01/203197660) actually made by Siemens and is Tier 1 quality gear.  ($25 + two $10 breakers).

"But I don't need 30 spaces" -- oh, you just watch!

- You will need 4 spaces for the above interlock
- A kitchen requires about 8 circuits to be Code, so 8
- Dedicated line for 2nd freezer (+1)
- Sump pump (1)
- Furnace MUST be on a dedicated circuit (1)
- eventually you will want to put a lot more circuits so you have the option of having them on generator (10)

So wow, we're at 25 spaces just like that.